# Kasteleyn, Gessel-Viennot and eigenvalues

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, random-matrices, statistical-physics, perfect-matchings

The Kasteleyn matrix (for counting perfect matchings) and the Lindström-Gessel-Viennot matrix (for counting families of nonintersecting lattice paths) are tightly related, as observed many times by Greg Kuperberg (see, for instance, his answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37603/is-there-a-group-whose-cardinality-counts-non-intersecting-paths) and also [this paper of his](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0108150)).

In particular, Kuperberg describes a "pivoting" operation which can be used to transform a Kasteleyn matrix into a related Lindström-Gessel-Viennot matrix while preserving the determinant.

The eigenvalues of a Kasteleyn matrix, at least, seem to be natural things to study.  I have "always" wondered: How are the eigenvalues of these two matrices related?

The pivoting operation seems to do something complicated to the eigenvalues.  Indeed, I suspect the relationship is complicated anyway, since the Kasteleyn matrix is much larger than the associated Lindström-Gessel-Viennot matrix.

However, the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues...  also each pivoting operation is subtracting a rank-one matrix from a maximal minor; there do exist theorems relating eigenvalues of a matrix to those of maximal minors, such as the [Cauchy Interlacing theorem for symmetric matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem).